# VueJS updates component keeping old values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm pretty new on VueJs. I have a `Practice` component which contains a `ExerciseMC` component. The parent component makes a request and gets a question object (with a text property) from the back and passes it to the `ExerciseMC` component as a prop. The first time the component is rendered, the text is rendered as it should but the second time, it renders the new title plus the old title and so on... I can't figure out where this "memory" comes from but it isn't the result that I expected...

Here is my `Practice` component:

```
<template>
<div>
    <h2>Practice</h2>
    <div id="activity">
        <span id="init" v-if="type === 'init'">
            Click on the "Next step" button when ready
        </span>
        <span id="mc" v-else-if="type === 'mc'">
            <exerciseMC :ex="ex"/>
        </span>
        <span id="sa" v-else-if="type === 'sa'">

        </span>
    </span>
    <hr/>
    <button type="button" id="btnValidate" @click="validate()">Validate</button>
    &emsp;
    <button type="button" id="btnSkip" @click="skip()">Skip</button>
    &emsp;
    <button type="button" id="btnNextStep" @click="nextstep()">Next step</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    import ExerciseMC from '../exercises_temps/ExerciseMC'
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        mounted(){
            console.log("Practicing");
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, "activity"]);
        },
        components: {
            exerciseMC: ExerciseMC
        },
        data(){
            return {
                type: 'init',
                ex: Object
            }
        },
        methods: {
            validate() {
                console.log("Validate");
            },
            skip() {
                console.log("Skip");
            },
            nextstep(){
                console.log("Next Step");
                const path = "http://localhost:8000/user/next-step";
                axios
                    .get(path)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.ex = {};
                        console.log("Response : ");
                        console.log(response.data);
                        this.ex = response.data;
                        this.type = response.data.type;
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log("Error");
                        console.log(error);
                    });

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is my `ExerciseMC` component:

```
<template>
<span id="exercise">
    <p id="text">{{ex.text}}</p>
</span>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props: {
            ex: Object,
        },
        mounted(){
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "exercise"])
        },
        beforeUpdate(){

        },
        updated(){
            console.log(this.ex);
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "exercise"])
        },
    }
</script>
```

Useful information : 
- I'm using MathJax to render math formulas in the text
- I already checked out the response from axios and the ex prop in the `ExerciseMC` component : everything is okay (the text changes every time and contains the text for each exercise)

I'm probably missing something about the Vuejs reactivity but I still can't figure it out after some researches

Comment: Could you create webpack snippet or upload minimal example on git? You can mock rest

Comment: how did you load MathJax into vue ?

Comment: I have this on my index.html : 
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
            extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
            jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
            tex2jax: {
            inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
            displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
            processEscapes: true
            },
            "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Editing since my previous suggestions did not work.

Try using a [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) on your component

```
<exerciseMC :key="ex.text" :ex="ex"/>
```

Comment: That didn't solve my problem. My components are reactive. The problem is that they keep in memory the old value instead of replacing them by the new ones

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edited my answer. Can you try it and let me know please?